# Saving a cookie inside a cookie

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, curl

I'm using CURL to access an xml API, and I need to save the COOKIEJAR somewhere, for technical reasons I can't save it in a file to read it back for the next call, I decided to save it in the user session (Codeigniter use cookie to store user's session), but I'm having this Error in codeigniter's log file.

```
ERROR - 2014-06-12 12:27:21 --> The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be a possible hacking attempt.
```

when saving it in the user's cookie, COOKIECEPTION I know it's strange, but this is the only way I thought it would work, now my question is this even possible ? or should I think on other ways ? I'm all ears for other propositions.

Comment: Use DB to temporary save cookie from CURL request?

Comment: Or try to serialize/json_encode the COOKIEJAR before saving it in a temp-cookie or session

Comment: @Dexa I'm leaving the DB as a last solution, because we're not using Mysql.
I did serialize/json_encode before asking, forgot to mention it.
and why I'm getting downvoted ?

Comment: try OCIA's suggestion, or if that can't work base64 encode/decode in a session...

Comment: @Dexa as I said I did serialize/json_encode before asking, it didn't work, but base64_encode made it, put your answer I'll accept it, thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment use base64 encode/decode and store value in the session. Reason why base64 works and serialize/json_encode doesn't is because you are not storing object/array value, but a string content of the file.